# Customizing headers in classic thesis

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, classicthesis

I am trying to customize the headers of my thesis with `classic thesis` and I do not know how to obtain the following result :

- left page : on the left, the number of the page, on the center, the title of the current section;
- right page : on the right, the number of the page, on the center, the title of the current chapter.

This is my preamble :

```
`% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage[tight,french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{../classicthesis} %,manychapters
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength\epitextskip
\pretocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\epigraph}{\@epitext{#1}\\}{\@epitext{#1}\\[\epitextskip]}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\setlength\epitextskip{2ex}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}

\FrenchFootnotes
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}
\frontmatter


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%modifie la taille des numéros de     chapitres%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@eulerchapternumbers}}% font for the chapter numbers
{\newcommand\mychapterNumber{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eur}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{28}  {29}\selectfont}}%
{\newcommand\mychapterNumber{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pplj}\fontsize{25}{26}\selectfont}}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{@linedheaders}}%
{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
    {\relax}{\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\\\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\mychapterNumber\thechapter}}{1.2em}%
    {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
}{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
    {\relax}{{\color{halfgray}\mychapterNumber\thechapter}}{1.2em}%
    {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
    }

    \begin{document}

%   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
%   \manualmark
%   \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}`
```

This is a view of what I am looking for : [image]

May you help me to do that ?

Comment: The headers in `classicthesis` are done with package `scrpage2` of the KOMA-bundle. Have a look at the documentation. I would give you a complete solution, but i don't have all the information i need. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: `\ohead{\pagemark}`, `\cehead{\rightmark}`, `\cohead{\leftmark}` Please note that left and right are switched as the standard is the other way around.

Comment: @dormi Could you bring us a full MWE?

Comment: @Johannes_B : I tried to to what you suggest, but I changed it in this way and it does not work : `\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{\pagemark}
\chead{\rightmark}
\cohead{\leftmark}`

Comment: You want the page number on the outside, right? So it would be ohead (for outer head). Your other commands also differ from the ones i provided earlier. Please check and come again.

Comment: No, I would like having it on the innerside. That is why I used `\ihead{\pagemark}`.

Comment: Left pages are even, right pages are odd. Take a few papers in your hand, hold them with your left hand and turn the pages with your right hand. Where would you want to place page numbers?

Comment: Hint: Add package `showframe`. The margin is always on the outer side.

Comment: It seemed to me that the innerside was even. That is why I used the previous command. I am about to use `showframe`.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) Why do you use package `classicthesis`? 2) Is your question answered?

Comment: I use this package in order to write my thesis. But I would like to have my headers in the way french edition does most of the times for books. My question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

In French  the `\leftmark` seems to be on the right page and the `\rightmark` on the left.

We should keep in mind, that `classicthesis` still uses the now obsolete package `scrpage2`.  With its successor `scrlayer-scrpage`, the commands below stay the same.

```
\ohead{\pagemark}%page on the outside
\cehead{\rightmark}%rightmark on even/left pages
\cohead{\leftmark}%leftmark on odd/right pages
```

Comment: Perhaps ... *Apparently in French language the `\leftmark` is...* sounds a little bit more ... polite ;-)